# aws athena convert array<array<string>> to table

Tags: sql, arrays, amazon-s3, type-conversion, amazon-athena

I have an s3 bucket that got a lot of files with this content:

```
{time:123456, state:{{1,2,3,4},{4,5,6,7}...}
```

and after I use Athena read it, the result is the dataset with 2 colums: the first one is time `int` and the second is `array<array<string>>`, is it possible to convert with athena sql this table to:

```
select time, col1,col2,col3,col4
from table
```

when the col1...4 is the names of the columns on the array?

Comment: Please add expected result, it will help to understand what exactly do you want to select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CROSS JOIN UNNEST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html) to unnest upper array:

```
select a.time, 
       state_array[1] as col1, 
       state_array[2] as col2,
       state_array[3] as col3,
       state_array[4] as col4
from my_table a
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(state) as t(state_array)
```